# How can I retrieve tenantId in a function triggered by onCreate in Google Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

**UPDATE: Partially Solved! See Below**

I've converted my Firebase application to multi-tenancy by upgrading to Identity Platform and I need to get tenantId in `onCreate` function.

```js
// This is where it's defined;
exports.processSignUp = functions.auth.user().onCreate(events.signUp);
```

This is the function, I've tried various things to get tenantId.

```js
  async function signUp(user, context) {
    let tenantId = user.tenantId; //context?.auth?.token?.firebase?.tenant;

    try {
      Logger.debug("USEROBJ", user);
      Logger.debug("USEROBJ-2", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user)));

      Logger.debug("CONTEXTOBJ", context);
      Logger.debug("CONTEXTOBJ-2", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(context)));
      if (!tenantId) {
        Logger.error("TENANT ID IS EMPTY", "Assigned manually.");
        tenantId = "xxxx-xxxx";
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }

    //Set Custom Claims on Firebase
    return (
      _createUserClaims(user.uid, user.email)
        //Read claims from store & update user's claims.
        .then(() => _updateClaims(tenantId, user.uid))
    );
  }
```

Claims creating function

```
//Merge custom claims with default claims.
const createClaimsObject = (uid, additionalClaims) => {
  const defaultClaims = {
    "x-hasura-default-role": "user",
    "x-hasura-allowed-roles": ["user"],
    "x-hasura-user-id": uid,
  };

  const claims = {
    "https://hasura.io/jwt/claims": {
      ...defaultClaims,
      ...additionalClaims,
    },
  };

  return claims;
};
```

This function is supposed to update claims, but it fails.

```js
function updateClaims(admin, firestore, tenantId, uid) {
  //
  return getClaims(firestore, uid)
    .then((doc) => checkClaims(uid, doc))
    .then((additionalClaims) => setClaims(admin, tenantId, uid, additionalClaims))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}
```

This is checking Firestore for claim records.

```js
//Check if claims exist.
const checkClaims = async (uid, doc) => {
  if (doc) {
    const data = doc.data();
    console.log(`${uid} has custom claims`, data);
    return data;
  }

  return {};
};
```

This is my claim setter function;

```js
const setClaims = async (admin, tenantId, uid, additionalClaims) => {
  const claims = createClaimsObject(uid, additionalClaims);
  return admin
    .auth()
    .tenantManager()
    .authForTenant(tenantId)
    .setCustomUserClaims(uid, claims);
};
```

After setting it manually, setClaims return this; `FirebaseAuthError: There is no user record corresponding to the provided identifier.`

How can I retrieve the tenant id and, even if I set it manually, why does it fail with this error?

> **How it's solved?**
>
> I don't exactly know why it's solved but I'll explain here how it's solved.
>
> - `admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);` this line updated with below
> - `admin.initializeApp();`
> - Another thing is when I log the `user` object there is no `tenantId` property but If I assign it to a value like `const tenantId = user.tenantId`
>   tenantId is there.
> - After signup, I was refreshing the token to get additional claims, but it wasn't there. It sometimes requires a second refresh, so adding
>   a timeout after the signup before fetching new token solves it.
>
> This solves my problem but it's not clear exactly and not a valid solution, answers are still welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the `tenantId` in a function triggered by `onCreate` in Google Cloud Functions, you can access it through the `context` parameter of the `onCreate` function.

Define your Cloud Function for user creation:

```
exports.processSignUp = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user, context) => {
  const tenantId = context.auth.tenantId || "defaultTenantId";
  // In the logic of your function, use the tenantId.
  //...
});
```

Access the `tenantId` using `context.auth.tenantId`. If it's not available, you can provide a default value.

Use the `tenantId` in your function's logic for further processing or customization based on the tenant.

You may check this documentation about [Cloud Function Event Context](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background#event_context).

Comment: Ty, context.auth.teantId is not available in the object.
I need it to be dynamic, not static, but I've tried that as well, the error is written in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in `context.auth.token.tenantId`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still wrestling with this, I have solved it by upgrading the Firebase community builder to the latest version. From then on, the `tenantId` property was sent in the `user` parameter.

If you use another way for deploying your functions check if your firebase-admin version is up to date.